# Working with event handlers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const divs_demo = document.querySelectorAll('.common');
const display_texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');



for(let div_demo of divs_demo){
    div_demo.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        for(let display_text of display_texts){
            display_text.style.display = 'block';
        };
    });
};
```

```css
.text{
    display: none;
}
.common{
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="common">
        <h1>Text one</h1>
        <p class="text">Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="common">
        <h1>Text two</h1>
        <p class="text">Good morning</p>
    </div>
    <div class="common">
        <h1>Text three</h1>
        <p class="text">Lets code</p>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Am working on with event handlers in JavaScript, however, have encountered a problem on my way, on the above code, I have got access to all the div elements in my html, and some hidden text which I want it to be displayed once the event handler which I have passed to the divs is performed, but once one div is clicked, it displays the all the text including the one on the other divs, but my target is to only display the text on the div which is clicked. Is there a way to do that without repeating the same code to every div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```js
const divs_demo = document.querySelectorAll('.common');
const display_texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

for (let div_demo of divs_demo) {
  div_demo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    div_demo.querySelector(".text").style.display = 'block';
  });
};
```

```css
.text{
    display: none;
}
.common{
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="common">
        <h1>Text one</h1>
        <p class="text">Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="common">
        <h1>Text two</h1>
        <p class="text">Good morning</p>
    </div>
    <div class="common">
        <h1>Text three</h1>
        <p class="text">Lets code</p>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: OP said "without repeating the same code!"

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do that without repeating the same code to every
> div?

Yes there's which is [`event-delegation`](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

```js
document.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.text').style.display = 'block';
})
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}

.common {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="common">
    <h1>Text one</h1>
    <p class="text">Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="common">
    <h1>Text two</h1>
    <p class="text">Good morning</p>
  </div>
  <div class="common">
    <h1>Text three</h1>
    <p class="text">Lets code</p>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, lemme look at it

Answer (score 1):

The displayed texts are children of the divs demo, so you can simply get the .text child of the div clicked. Here's how I would do it.

```js
const divsDemo = document.querySelectorAll('.common');
    
for (let divDemo of divsDemo) {
  divDemo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const clickedText = divDemo.querySelector('.text');
    clickedText.style.display = 'block';
  });
}
```

```css
.text{
    display: none;
}
.common{
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="common">
        <h1>Text one</h1>
        <p class="text">Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="common">
        <h1>Text two</h1>
        <p class="text">Good morning</p>
    </div>
    <div class="common">
        <h1>Text three</h1>
        <p class="text">Lets code</p>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

NOTE: It's highly recommendable that you respect style standards of the language that you're coding. In this case you should use camelCase naming for variables.
NOTE2: Instead of modifying the style, i would recommend you to use utility classes such as:

```
.invisible {
    display: none
}
```

And then appending or removing this class from the element that you want to disappear

Comment: okay thank you, but now once I click the next div demo, I want the previous one to hide it text. And also thank you for your recommendation about the styling

Comment: To do that, I would suggest maybe make all text invisible and the setting only the preffered.